# Using NLog's MappedDiagnosticsContext with ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack, nlog

I'm using NLog with my Servicestack service. I'd like to use NLog's MappedDiagnosticsContext to append a variable to each log entry. In my case, I'd like to generate a unique identifier for each request and have that identifier logged with all log entries logged during that request.

The `ServiceStack.Logging.ILog` interface (or any other servicestack logging class for that matter) doesn't seem to support this.

I can however do `NLog.MappedDiagnosticsContext.Set("somekey", "some value")`.  This works but ties me to NLog (I'm not to worried about that though).

Two questions:

1. Is there a better way to do this with servicestack.
2. Is it safe to assume that values set with NLog's MappedDiagnosticsContext are
   scoped to a request?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this since ServiceStack ver. 5.0:

```
using (log.PushProperty("Hello", "World"))
{
    log.InfoFormat("Message");
}
```

See also: https://docs.servicestack.net/logging

Answer (score 0):

I'm planning to use MappedDiagnosticsContext for these purposes:

EventID's for my event log targets: ${mdc:item=eventId}. We had been considering using an eventcontext property instead, but that changes the way you have to log items.

SessionId's for my other targets when logging about ASP.Net code: ${mdc:item=sessionId} since the ${aspnet-sessionid} way doesn't seem to work correctly for non-ASP code even with NLog 2.0.1.0 from NuGet.

My tests show that these cases make sense for my purposes.